# JQuery Table Sorting - More Efficient way?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm populating a table through PHP AJAX and am using JQuery to sort the columns.  Is there a more efficient way of coding this? :

```
$(document).on('click', '.thPartNumber', function() {
        if (clicked == 1) {
            fetch_data('PartNumber ASC');
            clicked = clicked + 1;
        }
        else if (clicked == 2) {
            fetch_data('PartNumber DESC');
            clicked = 1;
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.thPartName', function() {
        if (clicked == 1) {
            fetch_data('PartName ASC');
            clicked = clicked + 1;
        }
        else if (clicked == 2) {
            fetch_data('PartName DESC');
            clicked = 1;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think that question would better be answered on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could

- combine it into one click event and use `.hasClass()` to determine the part
- change the (int) `clicked` into (boolean) `clickFlag`

```js
var clickFlag = false;

$('.thPartNumber, .thPartName').on('click', function() {
  clickFlag = !clickFlag;
  var $this = $(this),
      order = clickFlag ? 'ASC' : 'DESC',
      name;
      
  if ($this.hasClass('thPartNumber')) {
    name = 'PartNumber';
  } else if ($this.hasClass('thPartName') {
    name = 'PartName';
  }
  
  fetch_data(name . ' ' . order);
});
```